# Using esri javascript to select points within a buffer

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to create a SELECT BUFFER using Javascript but I have not been able to do it properly. I have been able to create the buffer part of the program and it worked. However, I have not been able to use the buffer to select points that fall within it. I was wondering if anyone can assist me please.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples 
  on iOS devices-->
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>Buffer</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
   html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
  #leftPane{
    color:#000;
    width:250px;
    padding-bottom:15px;
  }
  #map{
    padding:0;
  }
  .details{
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:600;
    padding-bottom:20px;
  }

  button{
    margin:2px;
    cursor:pointer;
  }
</style>

<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.14/"></script>
<script>
var map, tb;

require(["dojo/dom",

        "dojo/_base/array",
        "dojo/parser",
        "dojo/query",
        "dojo/on",

        "esri/Color",
        "esri/config",
        "esri/map",
        "esri/graphic",

        "esri/geometry/normalizeUtils",
        "esri/tasks/GeometryService",
        "esri/tasks/BufferParameters",

        "esri/toolbars/draw",

        "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",

        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/tasks/query",

        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
        "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
        "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!"
        ],


      function(dom, array, parser, query, on, Color, esriConfig, Map, Graphic, normalizeUtils, GeometryService, BufferParameters, Draw, SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol, FeatureLayer, Query){

        parser.parse();


        esriConfig.defaults.geometryService = new GeometryService("http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

        esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/";
        esriConfig.defaults.io.alwaysUseProxy = false;


       //Setup button click handlers
        on(dom.byId("clearGraphics"), "click", function(){
          if(map){
            map.graphics.clear();
          }
        });
        //click handler for the draw tool buttons
        query(".tool").on("click", function(evt){
          if(tb){
           tb.activate(evt.target.id);
          }
        });

        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "streets",
          center: [-82.44, 28.3],
          zoom: 13
        });
        map.on("load", initToolbar);



      function initToolbar(evtObj) {
        tb = new Draw(evtObj.map);
        tb.on("draw-end", doBuffer);
      }

      function doBuffer(evtObj) {
        tb.deactivate();
        var geometry = evtObj.geometry, symbol;
        switch (geometry.type) {
           case "point":
             symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE, 10, new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new Color([255,0,0]), 1), new Color([0,255,0,0.25]));
             break;
           case "polyline":
             symbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASH, new Color([255,0,0]), 1);
             break;
           case "polygon":
             symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_NONE, new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASHDOT, new Color([255,0,0]), 2), new Color([255,255,0,0.25]));
             break;
        }

          var graphic = new Graphic(geometry, symbol);
          map.graphics.add(graphic);

          //setup the buffer parameters
          var params = new BufferParameters();
          params.distances = [ dom.byId("distance").value ];
          params.outSpatialReference = map.spatialReference;
          params.unit = GeometryService[dom.byId("unit").value];
          //normalize the geometry 

          normalizeUtils.normalizeCentralMeridian([geometry]).then(function(normalizedGeometries){
            var normalizedGeometry = normalizedGeometries[0];
            if (normalizedGeometry.type === "polygon") {
              //if geometry is a polygon then simplify polygon.  This will make the user drawn polygon topologically correct.
              esriConfig.defaults.geometryService.simplify([normalizedGeometry], function(geometries) {
                params.geometries = geometries;
                esriConfig.defaults.geometryService.buffer(params, showBuffer);
              });
            } else {
              params.geometries = [normalizedGeometry];
              esriConfig.defaults.geometryService.buffer(params, showBuffer);
            }

          });
        }

        function showBuffer(bufferedGeometries) {
          var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(
            SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
            new SimpleLineSymbol(
              SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
              new Color([255,0,0,0.65]), 2
            ),
            new Color([255,0,0,0.35])
          );

          array.forEach(bufferedGeometries, function(geometry) {
            var graphic = new Graphic(geometry, symbol);
            map.graphics.add(graphic);


          });
        var query = new Query();

          query.geometry = bufferedGeometries.getExtent();
          //use a fast bounding box query. will only go to the server if bounding box is outside of the visible map
          featureLayer.queryFeatures(query, selectInBuffer);    
        }
      var layer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://bccarct1:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CAPITAL_IMPROVEMENT_PROJECTS/crime/MapServer");  
      var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://bccarct1:6080/arcgis/rest/services/CAPITAL_IMPROVEMENT_PROJECTS/crime/MapServer/0",{
          outFields: ["Offense","Report_Dat","Street_Num", "Street_Nam", "Suffix", "City", "State", "Zip_Code"]
        });



      map.addLayer(featureLayer);

      // selection symbol used to draw the selected census block points within the buffer polygon
        var symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol(
          SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 
          12, 
          new SimpleLineSymbol(
            SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_NULL, 
            new Color([247, 34, 101, 0.9]), 
            1
          ),
          new Color([207, 34, 171, 0.5])
        );
        featureLayer.setSelectionSymbol(symbol); 

      function selectInBuffer(response){
          var feature;
          var features = response.features;
          var inBuffer = [];
          //filter out features that are not actually in buffer, since we got all points in the buffer's bounding box
          for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
            feature = features[i];
            if(circle.contains(feature.geometry)){
              inBuffer.push(feature.attributes[featureLayer.objectIdField]);
            }
          }
          var query = new Query();
          query.objectIds = inBuffer;
          //use a fast objectIds selection query (should not need to go to the server)
          featureLayer.selectFeatures(query, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW, function(results){
            var totalPopulation = sumPopulation(results);
            var r = "";
            r = "<b>The total Census Block population within the buffer is <i>" + totalPopulation + "</i>.</b>";
            dom.byId("messages").innerHTML = r;
          });
        }

        function sumPopulation(features) {
          var popTotal = 0;
          for (var x = 0; x < features.length; x++) {
            popTotal = popTotal + features[x].attributes["POP2000"];
          }
          return popTotal;
        }
 });


</script>

</head>

<body class="claro">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" 
     data-dojo-props="gutters:'true', design:'sidebar'" 
     style="width:100%;height:100%;">

  <div id="map" 
       data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" 
       data-dojo-props="region:'center'">
  </div>

  <div id="leftPane" 
       data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" 
       data-dojo-props="region:'left'">
    <div class="details">Pick a tool and draw on the map. The drawn graphic will be buffered based on the specified parameters.</div>
    <button type="button" class="tool" id="line">Line</button>
    <button type="button" class="tool" id="polyline">Polyline</button>
    <button type="button" class="tool" id="freehandpolyline">Freehand Polyline</button>
    <br/>
    <button type="button" class="tool" id="polygon">Polygon</button>
    <button type="button" class="tool" id="freehandpolygon">Freehand Polygon</button>
    <br/><hr />
    <div><b>Buffer Parameters</b></div>
    Distance: <input type="text" id="distance" size="5" value="660" />
    <select id="unit" style="width:100px;">
      <option value="UNIT_FOOT">Feet</option>
      <option value="UNIT_STATUTE_MILE">Miles</option>
      <option value="UNIT_KILOMETER">Kilometers</option>
      <option value="UNIT_METER">Meters</option>
      <option value="UNIT_NAUTICAL_MILE">Nautical Miles</option>
      <option value="UNIT_US_NAUTICAL_MILE">US Nautical Miles</option>
      <option value="UNIT_DEGREE">Degrees</option>
    </select><br />
    <button type="button" id="clearGraphics"  type="button">Clear Graphics</button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding distance and units to the query to fetch points within the buffer. Do something like this:

```
var query = new Query();
query.distance = [ dom.byId("distance").value ];
query.units = GeometryService[dom.byId("unit").value];
featureLayer.queryFeatures(query, selectInBuffer);
```